# Prime numbers in C

Tags: c

ok i have a very easy problem.we must find all the prime numbers that have at least 2 digits (11 is the first prime number).We must define the maxnumb.what the professor did .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXNUMB 100

int main (void) 
{
  int i,j;
     for (i=11 ; i<MAXNUMB; i+=2)
      { 
        for (j=3;j*j<=i;j+=2)
         {
           if (i%j==0)
           {

             break; 
           }
         } 
           if (j*j>i) 
           printf(''%d is prime\n'',i);
      }
   }`
```

so I have 3 questions

1. we use `"i=11"` because we want only the two digits primes but why `j=3` and not `j=11`
2. 8th line `"j*j<=i;` why he did that?what we gain?
3. why we have this `if (j*j>i)` and not something `(j==i)`

Comment: Even though you want primes that are starting at 11, you still need to check divisibility by odd numbers 3 and above. Otherwise, if you started at `j = 11` your program would say that , for example, 15 is prime (it's divisible by 5 and by 3).

Comment: thank you i got it.can you help with the second one?

Comment: When you are checking if a number is divisible by another, you only need to check up to the square root of the number. That's because if `n = a * b` and `a <= b`, then `a <= sqrt(n)`. So you only need to check `j < sqrt(i)` or (similarly) `j * j <= i`. And #3: `j*j > i` means that you went through ALL iterations of the loop without `i % j == 0` being true. `j == i` won't be true. It can't be true, because `j < sqrt(i)`.

Comment: On the third point, `j==1` does not prove or disprove primality, since all integers, **primes included**, have 1 as a factor.

Answer (score 2):

> why `j=3` and not `j=11`

Because `j` is your candidate *divisor*. You need to try all divisors up to square root except `2`, which has been eliminated by construction of the algorithm (you start with `11` and go up by `2`, so you see only odd numbers; no need to check divisibility by `2`).

> 8th line `j*j<=i;` Why he did that? What we gain?

If you tried all numbers up to and including the square root of the candidate prime, and found no divisors, then there would be no divisors above the square root as well. This saves you a lot of unnecessary iteration.

> why we have this if `(j*j>i)` and not something `(j==i)`

The loop terminates under two conditions: (a) you reach a `break`, or (b) `j` goes past the square root of `i`. If you reached `break`, it means you found a divisor; if you reached past the square root, you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the theory behind it:

> [image: P] is a prime number if there is no other factor like [image: j] in [image: P], which [image: 2 < j < strq(P)].

In your code, you are following the same path. The inner loop is trying all possible [image: j] less than or equal to [image: sqrt(i)].

> we use `"i=11"` because we want only the two digits primes but why `j=3` and not `j=11`

Based on what I just said, you should ask why [image: 3<j]! not [image: 2<j]? The answer is simple! `j` is a factor in `i` (e.g. 3 a factor in 12=3*2*2) In this code in order to make it even faster, you just skipped all even numbers (`i+=2`), then you don't need j=2 to check if 'i' is dividable by j.

> 8th line `"j*j<=i"` why he did that?what we gain?
>
> why we have this `if (j*j>i)` and not something `(j==i)`

Both questions are related to this part: [image: 3<j].

Comment: "... all possible `j` less than _or equal_ `sqrt(P)`".

Answer (score 0):

Trial Division Theorem: 
The most basic method of checking the primality of a given integer n is called trial division. This routine consists of dividing n by each integer m that is greater than 1 and less than or equal to the square root of n.

Hence, lets check primality of 37.

```
floor(sqrt(37)) = 6
```

So, check from 2 to 6, weather 37 is divisible by any of number in between. If 37 is not divisible by any number, then number is prime.

So, in your example:

```
floor(sqrt(11)) = 3  that's why started j = 3,
```

Also, instead of performing sqrt on i, we have considered square of j i.e. j*j <= i;

And, for last question answer by @dasblinkenlight is best.

Answer (score 0):

> we use "i=11" because we want only the two digits primes but why j=3 and not j=11

`i` is the number which is to be checked whether it is prime or not (since you need 2 digit numbers only so initially `i=11`) and your code is doing that by checking divisibility of `i` with `j`. So `j` should start from 2 but as your code neglects all even number due to `i+=2` (initially `i=11` so due to `i+=2` increment in loop we have values of `i=11, 13, 15,.. only odd numbers`) so there is no need to check divisibility of `i` with 2. Therefore initial value of `j` is 3.

> 8th line "j*j<=i; why he did that?what we gain?

It could be written as `j<=sqrt(i)` also. Assume `i=N^2` so if `N` is divisible by `j` then `N^2` is also divisible by `j`. So instead of checking divisibility of `i or N^2` with `j` till `j<i or j<N^2` we are limiting it to `j<=sqrt(i) or j<=N` which decrease the number of operations of divisibility check and hence decrease the execution time of program.

Assume `i=21` then  is `j=sqrt(i)` evaluates `j to be 4` (note j is `int` value so `sqrt(21)` result to be 4 instead of a `float` value `4.58`). So program will check divisibility of `i=21` with `j<=sqrt(i)` that is j=3(initial value) and 4(4<=sqrt(21)) instead with `j<i` that is j=3(initial value), 4, 5,... 20(20<21) which results in fasting the program.

We can also use `j<=pow(i,(1/3 or 1/4 or 1/n))` but this would be better after extremely high values of `i` (like >10^6) and would not work for smaller values.

> why we have this if (j*j>i) and not something (j==i)

It is because of the previous point.

Instead of checking divisibility of `i or N^2` with `j` till `j<=i or j<=N^2` we are limiting it to `j<=sqrt(i) or j<=N` which decrease the number of operations of divisibility check and hence decrease the execution time of program.

Hence if divisibility checking crosses the value `j*j>i or j>sqrt(i)` without having remainder equals to 0 or `i%j==0` to be false then `i` is proved to be prime and gets printed.